# VBA Excel 2010 - Paste directly from clipboard

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to paste directly from the clipboard into an excel document and have it so it is transposed

```
Dim DataObj As MSForms.DataObject
 Set DataObj = New MSForms.DataObject
 DataObj.GetFromClipboard

strPaste = DataObj.GetText(1)

strPaste.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteAll, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:= _
False, Transpose:=True
```

The `strPaste` does have the correct data but it bugs out on the `.PasteSpecial` saying object required

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you need to specify target where to paste and on it call `PasteSpecial method`. You cant call `pasteSpecial` method of string as you trying. (because of that error with object required)

Take a look at this

```
Sub testPaste()

    Dim DataObj As MSForms.DataObject
    Set DataObj = New MSForms.DataObject
    DataObj.GetFromClipboard

    strPaste = DataObj.GetText(1)

    Sheets("Sheet2").Rows(1).PasteSpecial Transpose:=True

End Sub
```

Comment: this works and does paste the data and is transposed however fit pastes the data all the way to the last column, using `Sheets("Sheet5").Cells(5, 1).PasteSpecial Transpose:=True` got it to paste only the data into a single column

Comment: @Mr.Burns so just play a bit with target, to where you need data to be pasted. I know nothing about data you wana to paste and where.

Comment: @Mr.Burns if you need anything else, feel free to ask. Im glad to help, but need more informations :) im not seer yet