# Paste data from clipboard

Tags: vba, clipboard, paste

I am trying to clean Sheet1 and paste directly from the clipboard (not from Excel) into Sheet1 cell A1 with paste special values. The reason it needs to be done this way is because the number of lines differs daily. At the moment i have below but i get Run-time error '1004': PasteSpecial method of Range class failed.

```
Dim clipboard As MSForms.DataObject
Dim str1 As String

Set clipboard = New MSForms.DataObject

Range("A1:K80").Select
Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
Selection.ClearContents

clipboard.GetFromClipboard

str1 = clipboard.GetText

Range("A1").Select
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
    :=False, Transpose:=False
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [VBA Excel 2010 - Paste directly from clipboard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36619386/vba-excel-2010-paste-directly-from-clipboard)

Comment: Can the object you are copying from the clipboard be interpreted as a `Range` object so that its `Value` property can be accessed?  (Note that the [Range.PasteSpecial Method (Excel)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/range-pastespecial-method-excel) documentation says that it "Pastes a **Range** that has been copied into the specified range."

Comment: @marius I have tried this post, but unfortanetly it didn't work for me.

Comment: @YowE3K, i am not sure. The data is Always from colomn A:J, but the rows differ daily from 3 till 80

Comment: "The data is Always from colomn A:J" - So you are copying from Excel.  Why not just do a standard copy/paste?  How are you getting the data into the clipboard?

Comment: Actually, looking at your code, isn't `str1 = clipboard.GetText` something that gets text data from the clipboard and puts it into the string `str1`.  I've never used that before, but perhaps it clears the clipboard as it does it.  What are you doing with `str1` after you have got it?  (You aren't using it in your posted code, but perhaps you use it later?)

Comment: Pulling data straight from the clipboard is really awkward and requires some API calls, YowE3K is right that you should just copy straight from the range. If it differs daily then change your code to copy different ranges, don't try to paste differently

Comment: No i copy the data from Simcorp but it has Always the same columns and headers.

Comment: @YowE3K, I used str1 instead of selection in the last row of the code but it didn't work either. Maybe my code is completely wrong, does any one have a suggestion?

Comment: Without knowing what you have on the clipboard, and why you are doing a `clipboard.GetText`, it's hard to tell what you should do.  It may be as simple as just doing a `Range("A1").Select: ActiveSheet.Paste` without mucking about with any of the `clipboard` stuff.  (Have you tried doing the paste manually?  Does it work when you do it?  If so, the `Range("A1").Select: ActiveSheet.Paste` method should work.)

Comment: Yes, thank you very much. It works perfectly now :)