# Copy and paste values only in Excel sheet

Tags: excel, vba, copy, copy-paste

I need only values to be pasted in a cell. so I manipulate `Ctrl` + `V` key to run following macro.

There are three possibilities of copied text.

1. Copied from web
2. copied from within excel sheet
3. cut from with excel sheet

Problem with following macro is only one condition (copy within sheet) is working. what should I change to get needed results?

**Updated:**

```
Sub PasteSP()
Dim DataObj As MSForms.DataObject
Set DataObj = New MSForms.DataObject
DataObj.GetFromClipboard

    Select Case Application.CutCopyMode
        Case Is = xlCopy

        Selection.Cells.PasteSpecial xlPasteValues

        Case Is = xlCut

        Selection.Cells.Paste ''Now problem lies here

        Case Is = False

            Selection.Value = DataObj.GetText(1)

    End Select

End Sub
```

Comment: If you are copying from a web page your `Ctrl` + `V` will return `False` because your copy won't be stored in Excel cache (for lack of better terminology).

Comment: To get around this, you need to create a data object to pull information from your clipboard rather than Excel cache as @Dean mentioned. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36619680/11936678) explains how this can be done.

Comment: @Plutian I edited my original question. now I'm facing only problem of cut and paste from excel sheet.

Comment: Use `.insert` instead of `.paste`